# Terminal error information right before sleep

Tags: boot, command-line, xubuntu, suspend

I run Xubuntu 20.04 and I'd like to know how to gather that terminal data that appears before the splash when turning on the computer, and especially the terminal data that shows up for like 125 milliseconds before the computer enters sleep mode. It always shows up some kind of warning but I can't read anything in time and I really don't want to ignore possible problems with my setup. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check `dmesg`, `journalctl -xe` and maybe the file .xsession-error. You might have a (redundant) log file: "/var/log/syslog", but that depends

Comment: The `dmesg` did the trick for me, thanks a bunch!